# Group By Multiple Columns Separately

Tags: mysql, group-by

I know that you can use the `GROUP BY` keyword to group by multiple columns, but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Table: Codes

user_id    day_of_week    id
------------------------------
  1          T             1
  1          W             2
  1          W             3
  2          F             4
  2          F             5
  2          M             6
```

And I am trying to find a command to output to get this:

```
Table: Codes

user_id    day_of_week    count(*)
-------------------------------------
  1          T              1
  1          W              2
  2          F              2
  2          M              1
```

So as you can see, it's grouping by the day of the week and the user_id Can someone help me achieve this with MySQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: (What does Thursday look like?)

Comment: I think thursday looks like `T` .. but who knows, `T` might be tuesday as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple columns in `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, day_of_week, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Codes
GROUP BY user_id, day_of_week
```